# Is there any platform where I can configure and test the Kubernetes Cluster creation in DevOps for free?

Tags: kubernetes, devops, cluster-computing

I am learning DevOps and there is no opensource platform where I can play around and test the concepts learnt in my training.

Is there any platform which is easy & convenient to use without giving my credit card details?

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking specific to Kubernetes playground, you can have a look at krea8labs k8s platform. I used it to test my k8s native applications without any restrictions.

Comment: Link:  https://krea8labs.com

Answer (score 2):

Try to work on-prem
[k3s](https://k3s.io/)

Gcloud,Azure and Civo will give you credits but with timeframe limit,when you can use your bucks.

Answer (score 1):

Signup for Azure Cloud https://azure.microsoft.com
test it for free there (check the free limits)

Answer (score 1):

You could use Kubernetes playground the session lasts for around 4 hours. But if you have a laptop with a good specification I would recomand to install docker and then use Minikube.

[Kubernetes playground](https://labs.play-with-k8s.com/#)

Comment: Please do leave an upvote if the answer helps